# Use xmlstarlet to add missing elements?

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I have a number of vendor records which contain multiple addresses e.g.

```
<vendor>
  <addresses>
    <address primary="yes">
      <line1 />
      <city />
      <state />
      ....
     </address>
     <address primary="no">
      <line1 />
      <city />
      <state />
      ....
     </address>
  </addresses>
</vendor>
```

Some required elements are missing -- preventing updating of the records. Can xmlstarlet can be used to add an element with a default value if it is missing?

Comment: Hmm. It's *possible*, but I don't know if you could do this very efficiently without writing your own XSLT template, *or* using the `pyx` and `p2x` subcommands to convert to the PYX textual representation and building your own script that does the fixup in that (easier-to-correctly-script) form. And at that point, might just use `xsltproc` and not need xmlstarlet at all.

Comment: With this particular data, the fields occur in a regular order, and some required fields require null values which also are unacceptable. 

Thinking of doing something really hacky like using sed to jam in a default tag right where good one would appear and then deleting all instances of my default tag followed by the beginning of a real one

Comment: A round-trip through pyx is definitely less hacky than that, and the logic is implementable with fairly similar (text-processing) tools (I'd probably go with awk rather than sed).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example. I'll use `xmllint --auto` for the xml source. Then we'll add an `<add-me>` element as a child of `<info>` if it doesn't exist using the identity transform pattern.

Source xml:

```
xmllint --auto
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>abc</info>
```

Add the missing element:

```
xmllint --auto | xsltproc add-missing.xsl -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info><add-me>some stuff</add-me>abc</info>
```

add-missing.xsl:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="info">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="not(add-me)">
                <add-me>some stuff</add-me>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another XSLT w/xmlstarlet option is to use a variable that contains the required elements (with or without default values) and treat is as a node set (using the supported `exsl:node-set()` function).

You can then iterate over the node set to see if an element with the same name already exists. If it does, use it. Otherwise use the default.

Example...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<vendor>
    <addresses>
        <address primary="yes">
            <line1>address 1 line1</line1>
            <state>address 1 state1</state>
        </address>
        <address primary="no">
            <line1>address 2 line1</line1>
            <city>address 2 city</city>
            <state>address 2 state</state>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</vendor>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (so.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="req_elems">
    <req>
      <line1/>
      <city/>
      <state/>
      <country/>      
    </req>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:variable name="ctx" select="."/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($req_elems)/req/*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$ctx/*[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$ctx/*[local-name()=local-name(current())]"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```xml
<vendor>
  <addresses>
    <address primary="yes">
      <line1>address 1 line1</line1>
      <city/>
      <state>address 1 state1</state>
      <country/>
    </address>
    <address primary="no">
      <line1>address 2 line1</line1>
      <city>address 2 city</city>
      <state>address 2 state</state>
      <country/>
    </address>
  </addresses>
</vendor>
```

Note: This only works if the only allowed elements in `address` are the same as `$req_elements`. For example, if you have an element named "foo" in address, it will be dropped from the output.